# POSTGRESQL query to extract attributes in JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have the below JSON in a particular DB column. I need a query to extract fields stored within the **savings rate(to and from)**.

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "data": {
        "intro_visited": {
          "portfolio_detail_investment_journey": true,
          "dashboard_investments": true,
          "portfolio_list_updates": true,
          "portfolio_detail_invested": true,
          "portfolio_list_offering": true,
          "dashboard_more_bottom_bar": true
        }
      },
      "type": "user_properties",
      "schema_version": "1"
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "savings_info": {
          "remind_at": 1583475493291,
          "age": 100,
          "savings_rate": {
            "to": "20",
            "from": "4"
          },
          "recommendation": {
            "offering_name": "Emergency Fund",
            "amount": "1,11,111",
            "offering_status": "not_invested",
            "ideal_amount": "1,11,111",
            "offering_code": "liquid"
          }
        }
      },
      "type": "savings_info",
      "schema_version": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the "To"

```
$..data.savings_info.savings_rate.to
```

To get the "From"

```
$..data.savings_info.savings_rate.from
```

Comment: Side note: I use this website to help write these codes: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

Comment: If my table name is user and column name is json_data hw do i write this script? Sorry i'm a complete newbee :(

Comment: The site I posted has some really good documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This script works

```
SELECT 
<column> ->'data'->2->'data'->'savings_info'->'savings_rate'->>'to' AS to_rate
from <table>
```